# "Unresolved external symbol" for templated function declared inline in header

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project equivalent to this:

**Header.h**

```
template< class T >
inline int Demonstrate( const char *txt, T *input )
{
  return printf("%s %d %f\n", txt, input->Integer(), input->Real() );
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"

class Foo 
{
public:
   int Integer() { return 2; }
   float Real() { return 3.14159f; }
};

int main()
{
   Foo example;
   printf( "%d\n", Demonstrate( "foo:", &example ) );
   return 0;
}
```

Yet when I compile I receive a LNK2019 error:

```
unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl Demonstrate(char const *,class Foo *)"
```

Ordinarily this occurs when a templated function is declared in a header but only defined in a cpp, but **that is not the case here**. The function is defined inline in the header.

What could cause this and how can I fix it?

**edit**

This happens even if I remove the header altogether and just stick Demonstrate() at the top of Source.cpp. It happens whether "Inline Function Expansion" in the project properties is set to "Default" or to `"/Ob2"` . This must be some project settings thing, but what?

Comment: Compiled fine for me with VS 2012.

Comment: @Hna Yes, there is clearly something anomalous about this case since I have inlined template functions many other times without trouble. I'm at a loss for what the problem is here.

Comment: Your function says it returns `int` but the error message says `bool` - are you sure it's calling what you think it's calling?

Comment: The code, as posted, is fine. Are you sure that when you say your posted code is "equivalent", that it's actually equivalent? It sounds like something else is going on. Is there any more information you can provide? Can you reproduce it in a small self-contained project and post it all here? At this point in time, the real problem seems to be that the post is not representative of the code producing the error. :)

Comment: @Joel No, that was just a typo on my part; fixed.

Comment: Code compiles and runs correctly for me, VS2012 x64 - with the addition of `#include <stdio.h.>`.

Comment: OK, but I'd say the question still stands. Are you sure it's calling what you think? That code as you've posted it compiles fine for me, too.

Comment: @Joel The strange thing is that Demonstrate() is not declared or externed anywhere but in that header. Neither are there any overloads. The problem cropped up when I converted it from `Demonstrate( const char *, Foo *)` to `template<class T> Demonstrate( const char *, T *)`

Comment: This isn't by any chance in a library is it?

Comment: @Joel No, it's an .exe . How could it be a library? VS wouldn't try to link symbols at all in that case.

Comment: could it be some lingering data of a previous build which is confusing the compiler? Did you try rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: I was asking because this has some of the marks of a mismatch between a header file and what's in a static library, for example. In particular, you might see this behavior if you previously had your non-template in a header and then changed it to a template but the cpp file was still seeing the old header.

Comment: Or, what @didierc said :)

Comment: @didierc Yeah, "rebuild" was the first thing I tried. =/

Comment: Very odd. Whatever the problem is, it doesn't seem to be here, because everyone else seems to be able to use exactly that code successfully. What project options have you customized, and can you reproduce the problem with a project that literally uses the code you've posted here?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure, it happens to everyone.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a particular codebase and not a general issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about error in code that is not posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tracked this down and it turns out that Joel was on the right path. The function Demonstrate() had been prototyped multiple times in multiple headers — in a very nonobvious way. There was the explicit `int Demonstrate( const char *txt, Foo *input )` declaration, which is what I replaced with a template.

But there were several other headers that had, strewn across them, something analogous to this (you can infer that the actual function and class names were much more complicated):

`header a.h:`

```
#define FUNC_PREFIX Demo
```

`header b.h:`

```
#define REGISTER_CLASS( retype, classname, FUNC_SUFFIX ) retype FUNC_PREFIX ## FUNC_SUFFIX ( const char *txt, classname *ptr )
```

`header c.h:`

```
REGISTER_CLASS( int, Foo, nstrate );
REGISTER_CLASS( int, Bar, nstrate );
// etc
```

I'm not sure what to draw from this. On the one hand it's a very specific bug to a very specific codebase and too localized to be a useful SO question. On the other hand, there is a teachable moment here:

**DON'T USE MACROS TO DEFINE GLOBAL FUNCTIONS IN SNEAKY WAYS**.

Or else poor saps like me will spend hours tracking down problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can't rely on automatic template specialization.  I've encountered this before with VS and ended up having to be explicit.  *ie*

```
Demonstrate<Foo>("foo:", &example)
```